# Display all transactions on date Python > HTML output. grouped by day

Tags: python, html, mysql

I have a MySQL table that returns data as follows.

```
TransactionDate | Transaction
-----------------------------

 - 01/01/2017     |   1  
 - 01/01/2017     |   2  
 - 02/01/2017     |   3 
 - 02/01/2017     |   4  
 - 02/01/2017     |   5
```

I would like to display all transactions on a day under the date as follows using Python | Flask | HTML

- 01/01/2017

  - 1
  - 2
- 02/01/2017

  - 3
  - 4
  - 5

Now I know I can create a dictionary and loop through it or just iterate through the date. But I am new to Python . What would be the best way to approach this.

Comment: `{%for client in data2 %}
          <tr>
          <td>{{ loop.index }}</td>
          <td>{{ client[5] }}</td>
         </tr>
                                {% endfor %}` - Is what im currently doing, but its still adding all rows and not just distinct dates PS : Client[5] is my TransactionDate

Answer (score 0):

```
 unique = {}
                    for dates in data_booking_form:
                        if dates[5] not in unique:
                            unique[dates[5]] = []
                        unique[dates[5]].append(dates)
```

Worked for me

Now I am struggling to get the display in HTML to order by dates.
When I run my query, it is order by dates and it is a date field !
It returns the dates in a different order though

Any Ideas?